# Is it possible to query deleted comments (not owned by me)?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The motivation is a bit frivolous, I must confess: my top voted answer used to have a "+1" comment praising my writing style (I can't remember the exactly wording but it was something about my sense of humor and it being "normal English" instead of "geek English").

Of course that was totally accidental because English is not my native language and I can barely spell, but nonetheless I was proud of it because it had like 20 upvotes. I do not want to debate whether this kind of comment adds something to the site, I just want to recall the exactly wording and score.

Is my favorite comment forever lost?

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9708902/168175 you think? I can't see any deleted comments on that question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant my best voted answer instead of question - Jon Clements found it already, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge deleted comments can only be seen by mods.

So you may figure out how to ask one of the mods in a friendly way and possibly get text of that comment to enjoy.

Comment: So I can't do this unless I get a diamond next to my name - nice to know anyway.

Comment: @PauloScardine looks like you were after *+1 for sense of humor and for the fact the post is written in normal English, not geek English* (it had 21 votes)

Comment: You are the best, @JonClements.